# Having some issue with Eclipse and JRE

Tags: java, eclipse

I have installed JRE 8 on my system (Windows 7). But when I try to find it in Eclipse, it doesn't show it. Also when I compile program which need updated JRE 8, Eclipse doesn't compile it . What should I do ?

Comment: Install a JDK, not a JRE.

Comment: Which JRE? Which Eclipse? Try to find it how? What does "doesn't compile it" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Goto Window -> Preferences (as in image below) and browse to Java -> Installed JRE.
If no JRE is listed add new one and give the path to the installed JRE location.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGsmk.png)

Screen shot of Preferences Window